# How to get uncompressed filename after zlib_decode()?

Tags: php, compression

I am using zlib_decode() to uncompress a GZ file. How do I get the umcompressed file name after that?

Comment: The zlib header does not always contain the original filename. And PHPs built-in decoding functions don't provide access to it even. -- Elaborate a bit on your question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am building a service where you can upload an SQL dump file either in raw or GZ format for some processing. In order to output a changed file, I need to know the original filename.

Comment: Show your code, expectations and result

Answer (score 0):

You will need to extract the file name from the header yourself.  Read the [RFC that describes the gzip header and trailer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952).  It's pretty easy to do.

Comment: Can you show me an example PHP code? I don't see anything helpful in those specs.

Comment: No, I'm not going to write your code for you.  The specs tell you exactly the format of the header.  You just need to examine the first few bytes to see what fields are present in the header, and then find the fields in the subsequent bytes.  If you are not willing to read and understand the specs, then you are asking your question in the wrong place.  You need to find some other forum where people will do the work for you.  (When you find that forum, please post back here to let us know where it is.  Thanks.)

Comment: Ok, I will rephrase my question. How do I get the GZ header with PHP?

Comment: Is the gzip stream in a string?  If so, simply index the string to look at it a byte at a time.  str[0], str[1], etc.  You can use the PHP bitwise operators to check individual bits in the bytes.